# MySQL Insert / On duplicate key failure

Tags: mysql

I have some code which is trying to update existing rows of a table with new values for 2 columns. The row will always exist. It has a primary key and also a further unique field, and the update specifies the unique field. I am doing this using INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

However this was not updating the row, rather it updates a row that happens to exist with a primary key of 0. If no row exists with a primary key of 0 then it works perfectly.

I think what is happening is that as I do not specify a primary key MySQL is choosing a value of 0 for this somewhere, then it updates the row with a primary key of 0 rather than the actual row whose unique index I specify.

I do note that the manual pages say :-

**In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.**

The issue can be demonstrated as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE fred
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL,    
    code varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    stock int(5) NOT NULL,
    is_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY code (code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO fred VALUES
(0, 'a', 123, 1),
(2, 'b', 234, 1),
(3, 'c', 345, 1);
```

With this data the following insert should update the 2nd row (primary key 2, unique index on code of **b** ), but instead it updates the 1st row with the primary key of zero and the unique index on code of **a** .

```
INSERT  INTO fred (code,stock,is_active) VALUES ('b',46,68) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = VALUES(stock), is_active = VALUES(is_active);
```

Short of switching to specifying the primary key for this (or a bodge of just removing the record with a primary key of 0), rather than the unique key I am at a loss as to how to cleanly fix this.

Comment: Shouldn't your id has `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: I can't recreate your issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d37d/1/0

Comment: The id should not have auto increment on it (essentially the id and code are generated from an external system - the code is meaningful to some areas while the id is used for joining tables efficiently). Using auto increment stops the id of 0 being used, and with no id of 0 the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: @lad2025 - with auto increment removed the problem is apparent - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e4a/1

Comment: Why isn't the `id` your own primary key (auto incremented) and you add `foreign_id` key which can be whatever value and it corresponds to the number that the external system gives you, along with `code`?

Comment: If could be, but would be meaningless and not useful for anything beyond fixing this issue. That might be the best solution but might cause future confusion with other tables joining via a unique id that is not the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of what you want to do:

```
CREATE TABLE fred (
   id int(11) NOT NULL,
   `code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   stock int(5) NOT NULL,
   is_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
   UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO fred (id, code, stock, is_active) VALUES
(1, 'a', 123, 1),
(2, 'b', 234, 1),
(3, 'c', 345, 1);
```

Then to update you need to send the ID as well, but the primary unique key is code.

```
INSERT  INTO fred (id, code, stock, is_active) VALUES (98, 'b',46,68) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = VALUES(stock), is_active = VALUES(is_active), id = VALUES(id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is using AUTO_INCREMENT which is not an option in this case (it is not an automatically generated field from MySQL - the number is a unique integer assigned by an external system).

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. You can still force the I'd even if the field is AI

Comment: Unfortunately not - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde13 . Inserts 0 to the auto increment id field but when selected it shows that it used an id of 1.

Comment: Ok, i have now updated my answer. This seems to work on my end!

Comment: The issue with that is that it needs both keys (which may or may not be available - and introduces the possiblity of a mismatch between the 2 keys with one of them then randomly chosen to be updated), and this code is used in various places. Both really need to be set as unique keys (the reason for this is that the integer id is used for efficiency on loads of other tables, but is allocated externally to cope with worries over rebuilding the database in future - something I doubt will ever be required).

Comment: Possibly should add that the item with an id of 0 should actually have a different value for it (it is in error), so to fix this issue I can just delete the record. But I am worried about similar situations on other tables, and concerned that this appears to be a bug where MySQL appears to update the wrong record.

Comment: Couldn't you just have another table with code to interesting relationships? That way you can do your other table joins in the into but keep the code as the only primary unique key in this table?

Comment: For most things the code is the important figure, especially updates, and this is already the only table that uses that code. But being a character it is pretty poor for the joins required to display data. Hence for reads the unique integer is important for performance, and this is in effect the link table. This is only a issue with MySQL appearing to decide to behave inconsistently should there be a record with a primary key of 0.