# MySQL: "Duplicate entry for key", but in DB we can see it is not duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using

INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

and it worked well for a few months (it inserts data or updates row if key already exists). Today all of a sudden I am getting:

```
Duplicate entry 'somekey' for key 'unique_key'
```

I went to phpMyAdmin and searched for 'somekey' and there is only one row, so no duplicates.

What could be wrong?

Comment: using auto Incremental Pkey?

Comment: Can you share more details? Have you checked whether the data to be inserted might also contain a row with `somekey`?

Comment: Indeed like @NicoHaase said.. computers can not a lie so the error is valid so it pretty clear the inserted data is a duplicate there is no other way to interpreteert the error message

Comment: Once there is already one value of 'somekey' stored in the database, then the next one being inserted is a duplicate. So if the 'slug' contain a 'bitcoin' value, then your insert is trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: @ino, yes, that is why I have ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, so in this case only the values should be updated. And it worked well for a long time.

Comment: What kind of key is the `slug`?

Comment: Do you have other unique keys in your table?

Comment: @ino It is unique key (but no primary). I have attached a screenshot in main question.

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, there are two unique keys: id (INT, primary) and slug(varchar(40)).

Comment: @PrimožKralj Check out database normalization (Normal Forms). It will be easier for managing your database. All the delete and update dependencies will disappear. Right now, your tables seem like a mess, no wonder debugging is hard

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich this is definatelly something I need to look into as soon as I fix this issue.

Comment: I rewrote the code to use `UPDATE .. SET ... WHERE" and it works. But this means no new rows will be created if there is a new slug in town.

Comment: @PrimožKralj Yes, trust me when I say that it makes your life exponentially easier when managing your DBs. I always apply up to 4th normal form (BCNF). This becomes incredibly apparent when your DBs scale significantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table already contain a value `'bitcoin'` in the field `'slug'`.

Therefore attempt to insert another row containing `'bitcoin'` in the field `'slug'` will raise an error `"Duplicate entry 'bitcoin' for key 'slug'"` since the `'slug'` is an key column no matter of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`.

The `slug` is unique key = only one occurrence is possible in whole table no matter what ID it will have.

Comment: How can I solve this? It should insert the row if the slug does not exist yet, otherwise update the values.

Comment: Yes, I have it.

Comment: I have had odd results with inserts using "ON DUPLICATE KEY" when there is a primary key with an id of 0. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021816/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-failure